# mysql drop partition does not work

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have created main partition 20170621 and 24 sub partitions
20170621_0 .. 20170621_23

Now I would like to  delete the main partition. But I get an error.

```
alter table VAL90W02  drop PARTITION `20180621`
```

> #1508 - Cannot remove all partitions, use DROP TABLE instead.

I can´t drop sub-partitions either. So, how do I drop the partition?

(from Comment)

```
create table mytable (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    ..., 
    x_date datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id, x_date)
) ENGINE = MYISAM
PARTITION BY RANGE (day(x_date))
SUBPARTITION BY HASH (hour(x_date))
( PARTITION 20180621 VALUES LESS THAN (24)
   ( SUBPARTITION 20180621_0 ENGINE = MyISAM,
     SUBPARTITION 20180621_1 ENGINE = MyISAM, ...)
), ...;
```

Comment: I'll add this to my list of why Subpartitions are not worth using.

Comment: Would you care to share `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (including the partition stuff).  There may be some clues of what to do next.

Comment: Thank you, I hope following lines are enough .create table mytable (  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 ... x_date  datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`x_date`   ENGINE = MYISAM  PARTITION BY RANGE ( day(x_date))
                SUBPARTITION BY HASH (hour(x_date))(

                PARTITION `20180621` VALUES LESS THAN (24) (


                SUBPARTITION `20180621_0` ENGINE = MyISAM,
                SUBPARTITION `20180621_1` ENGINE = MyISAM,
    ...

Answer (score 0):

Irritatingly, when deleting **the last partition** of a partitioned table, you have to use

```sql
ALTER TABLE VAL90W02 REMOVE PARTITIONING;
```

instead.

This is a misleading error thrown by MySQL (I'm using 5.7 Aurora, not sure which versions this affects).

Arguably, it's a failure of MySQL to handle the edge case on the part of the `ALTER TABLE DROP PARTITION` command.